Unable to insert or update data using Python into PostgreSQL
I am trying to create a script to read a csv file and update my local postgreSQL table. This is the data I am trying to upload.
import psycopg2 as pg
from pandas import read_excel,DataFrame

def execute_query(connection,cursor,query:str):    
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()

def create_conn():
    try:
        connection = pg.connect("host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='abc' user='abc' password='abc'")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        return connection,cursor
    except:
        print("Connection failed")

def read_sql_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        sql_queries = file.read()
    return sql_queries

def import_csv_data(connection, cursor, csv_file,tablename):
    try:
       df = read_excel(csv_file)

       for i,row in df.iterrows():
           values = ",".join(map(str,row.values))
           query = f"INSERT INTO {tablename} VALUES {values};"
           execute_query(connection,cursor,query)

    except Exception as e:
       print(f"Error: {e}")


def close_connection(connection,cursor):
    connection.close()
    cursor.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    conn, curr = create_conn()
    if conn and curr:        
        
        ## Create table
        # sql_file = "player_behaviour_create.sql"  
        # query = read_sql_file(sql_file)                        
        # execute_query(conn,curr,query)

        ## Insert Data
        import_csv_data(conn,curr,r"Data\data_sample_100_rows.xlsx","player_behaviour")    

        close_connection(conn,curr)
        

SQL Query for table creation:
CREATE TABLE player_behaviour (
    PlayerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Age INT,
    Gender VARCHAR(10),
    Location VARCHAR(50),
    GameID INT,
    PlayTime FLOAT,
    FavoriteGame VARCHAR(50),
    SessionID BIGINT,
    CampaignID INT,
    AdsSeen INT,
    PurchasesMade INT,
    EngagementLevel VARCHAR(10)
);

I am getting the following error:

What I suspect is since I am converting everything into a string (import_csv_data), there is a datatype mismatch happening, but I am not sure. If this is so, what can I do?
I could also use some tips to optimize this code.

were you getting errors. It's not clear where you want us to come in

You don't need pandas for this simple task.  Just use the csv module to read the file, that way you are in COMPLETE control of the formatting of the INSERT statement.

@AkinniyiAkinbodeBolade Yes I am. Sorry, I forgot to update the error. Attached screenshot now.

The VALUES clause must be wrapped in parentheses: INSERT INTO tbl (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 'a', 'b'). Voting to close as a typo

Note that using f-srtings to interpolate values into SQL statements is not a good idea - use parameter substitution instead.

Each row you're inserting must be wrapped in parens.
insert into table(a,b,c) 
values (1,2,3);

See SQL tutorial: INSERT.

Two notes. First, don't concatenate SQL values as strings. This leaves you vulnerable to a visit from Little Bobby Tables aka a SQL Injection Attack. Use parameter substitution.
Second, you can insert multiple rows in a single insert. This makes bulk loading significantly faster.
insert into table(a,b,c) values
  (1,2,3),
  (4,5,6),
  (7,8,9);


Thanks everyone for the great advice. I wasn't aware of parameter substitution. The following function is the final version that worked:
def import_csv_data(connection, cursor, csv_file):
    try:
        with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
            csv_reader = reader(f)
            next(csv_reader)

            for row in csv_reader:
                vals = (r for r in row)                
                query = """INSERT INTO player_behaviour 
                (PlayerID,Age,Gender,Location,GameGenre,PlayTimeHours,InGamePurchases,GameDifficulty,SessionsPerWeek,AvgSessionDurationMinutes,PlayerLevel,AchievementsUnlocked,EngagementLevel)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s);"""                
                cursor.execute(query, (int(row[0]),
                                        int(row[1]),
                                           row[2],
                                           row[3],
                                           row[4],
                                           float(row[5]),
                                           int(row[6]),
                                           row[7],
                                           int(row[8]),
                                           int(row[9]),
                                           int(row[10]),
                                           int(row[11]),
                                           row[12]))
        connection.commit()
        print("Data imported successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error importing data: {e}")

Note: I made a few mistakes in column names, so made sure to correct that.
